# GitHub Mac OS application is launched but its application window is hidden

Tags: macos, mac, git

I just installed GitHub Mac OS application. I do some work with that, closed it and then open it again. After that the application opens but apparently the application window is hidden. I can work with GitHub menus in top of screen but can not see any of the the windows.

Also I can see the GitHub process in Activity Monitor but the screen is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to change the screen resolution, then back again. This should force all windows on-screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have a multi-monitor setup at work but not at home so I have this happen with apps from time to time. I've successfully tried this with GitHub, Sublime Text, iTerm, Chrome, Word and Excel.

An equally simple solution is to open GitHub and the hit **CMD**+**W** to close out the active window. You can now open a new window or restart the app to have it appear in the native resolution.